# AOSP downloading just one flavour (ICS) source code

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-source

This might be a trivial question but I dont know the answer to it. Looking for android gurus.
My task is to compile android kernel and run on a pandaboard. I cannot just take the uImages there are drivers which I need to modify..

Now one way is to download every thing from AOSP by repo init... and downloading 3-4 Gb of git from day 1 of android git init. 
Is there a way to just get the source files for ICS. It is easy for linux just go to git.kernel.org and get the snapshot of the tag like 3.0 , is there a same git snapshot available in android ?

Any help is welcome....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Not likely. Don't bother and simply `repo sync` to the branch you need.

Longer explanation:

If somebody has created snapshot of your particular tree, then you might be able to do that.

However, I don't think anybody will bother to do so, because having this git-less snapshot is pretty much useless from developer's standpoint, and space/traffic savings over `repo sync` are miniscule.

Note that git is *extremely* efficient at packing historic metadata in object store (provided it was packed by `git gc` recently). It is relatively rare situation when compressed git metadata takes more space than simple checkout of the top of the tree. Since `repo sync` only downloads compressed metadata, this process is very efficient.

So speed this up even further and avoid handling small objects, Android projects creates single-file compressed [bundles](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) for most repositories included in standard manifest, and modern `repo` script understands how to get these bundles first for efficiency, and then get small deltas afterwards. This allows to perform first `repo sync` much faster than otherwise. Basically, you are only limited by the speed of your internet connection.

Comment: i agree but i have a limit of 15G on my 3g data card connection and I have used 4G already :). What I am looking for is filtering repo sync so that I can get say only android for a particular platform only.

Comment: You can use any older copy of repo as your starting point. Just fetch latest manifest and checkout to your branch. Then `repo sync` will work faster and download less, even if your repo was not exactly the same.

Comment: hmm if thats the only way then I need to download and compile a lot :(